# How to read multiple files with MultiResourceItemReader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a `tar.gz` archive with about 1 million files. I want to use `MultiResourceItemReader` from `spring-batch` to read those files.

Problem: the `MultiResourceItemReader` requires the `resources` set up on initialisation. But I don't want to initialize all of the 1mio files before the import starts. Instead I'd like to have the MultiResourceItemReader read the archive file by file, and pass each file through the batch import instead of allocating all files on startup.

How could I achive this?

Comment: Reader can be configured with `scope=step` and be autowired values that you set at runtime in your job. Would that work?

Comment: No, I just want to somehow force the MultiResourceItemReader to read each file being processed fresh from the archive, instead of requireing all resources being directly set during initialization.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "initialize"? Do you mean you don't want to untar the file but instead read directly in it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to write your own `CompressedFileMultiResourceItemReader` which acts as a `MultiResourceItemReader` but accept:

1. a single compressed file
2. a list of matching paths

`CompressedFileMultiResourceItemReader` should iterate through compressed file entries, match paths and - if a match is found - create a [`VfsResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/VfsResource.html) (or a custom `AbstractResource` that apply to an entry of your VFS) and pass it to a delegate to perform real reading.
Of course your own reader must cares about its status

- Current entry
- Current delegate state
- Other state properties

to allow restartability.
This is just an idea; I haven't time to make it concrete because currently I haven't spare time for this :(

Comment: Nice idea! How would you keep track of which file you have read to make it restartable?

Comment: you can count every entry during enumeration so just store entry index. on restart skip entries for a count of stored index

Comment: That's a great concept. However, what is the `VfsResource`? Why should I use this resource, what is it for? What has a "Jboss Resource" to do with reading an archive file?

Comment: A `VfsResource` is a Spring `Resource` for virtual-file-system. I haven't used that, but if VfsResource doesn't apply for Apache-VFS you have to write a custom `AbstractResource` implementation based on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/VfsResource.java

Answer (score 1):

Using [Apache-VFS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/index.html), you can read files in a tar archive as you would do files on a "traditional" filesystem.

[As presented here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html#Zip_Jar_and_Tar), the resource path would then be : `tar:// arch-file-uri[! absolute-path]`.
Example with a `tar.gz` file : `tar:gz:http://anyhost/dir/mytar.tar.gz!/mytar.tar!/path/in/tar/README.txt`.

Now, Spring Batch `MultiResourceItemReader` can read multiple files by specifying a wildcard in the resource name.
Example : `<property name="resources" value="file:C:/files/file*.txt" />`

What I suppose you can try to do is override the method `setResource(Resource resource)` of the default `MultiResourceItemReader` to add support for Apache-VFS.

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Luca, `MultiResourceItemReader` doesn't have a `setResource(Resource resource)` method but instead has `setResources(Resources[] resources)`.

That being the case, I don't think it invalidates this lead. In fact, it seems to me that there is underlying [`ResourcesItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourcesItemReader.html), which converts wildcards to a Resources Array.

This means that you can declare a new String property to ask for the resource path and maybe use a [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) to resolve actual resources.

Here are a few lines of code you might find useful to begin :

```
public class CustomMultiResourceItemReader extends MultiResourceItemReader {

    private String resourcesPath;

    @Override
    public void setResources(Resources[] resources) {

        this.resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(resourcesPath)
    }

    public void setResourcesPath(String resourcesPath) {
        this.resourcesPath = resourcesPath;
    }
}
```

Now I think that you need to create a custom `ResourceLoader` to be able to actually resolve resources with Apache-VFS.

Comment: `MultiResourceItemReader` doesn't have a `setResource()` method but a `setResources(Resource[])` one. I think your solution is not applicable

Comment: Extension of out-of-the-box components should be avoided as much as possible; is preferrable extend abstract class or implements interface and work with delegation